# How do you style an HTML middot?

Tags: html, css, text, symbols

So, in my HTML, I'm putting 3 middots (dots that are vertically centered)

```
&middot; &middot; &middot;
```

and I want to style them. I want to make them larger. I also want to make the first dot white and put a blue circular outline around it, while making the other two dots gray.

Any idea if that's possible and if yes, how to go about it?

Comment: What is so special about these being *mid dots*? How is this different from asking how to style *any other* character?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To make them larger, just use the [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size?v=example) property in combination with [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height). To only style the first dot, you need to wrap it into a `<span>` and style it separately. The blue border can be achieved by using the [`text-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) property:

```css
div {
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: .4em;
  color: gray;
}

div>span {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div><span>&middot;</span>&middot;&middot;</div>
```

You can even make the outline bolder, if you use 4 text shadows in 4 different directions:

```css
text-shadow:
  -1px -1px 0 blue,
  1px -1px 0 blue,
  -1px 1px 0 blue,
  1px 1px 0 blue;
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: .4em;
  color: gray;
}

div>span {
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 blue, 1px -1px 0 blue, -1px 1px 0 blue, 1px 1px 0 blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div><span>&middot;</span>&middot;&middot;</div>
```

Comment: I should've specified that I wanted a blue circular outline around the white dot, not a square blue border, but this is great, thanks!

Comment: @AlgorithmicProgrammer `border-radius: 50%;`

Comment: It should be noted that the seemingly obvious answer of using the :first-letter pseudo-element selector does not work with middot (and other special characters).